# Android SDK and AVD Manager installation

Tags: android, eclipse

I am new to android development.

Have tried a couple times downloading the Android SDK and ADT plugin for Eclipse

In the Android SDK and AVD manager load fine but will not load any available packages.
Show:
- Android Repository
--"Some packages were found but are not compatible updates"

In the installed it shows 1.5 to 2.3 SDK platforms.

How to I get them available.

Appreciate help.

Thanks,

Alex

Answer (score 25):

You can use following step:

```
1.  window  ->  
2.  customize perspective -> 
3.  command group availability tab -> 
4.  on the check box android SDK and AVD manager check it -> 
5.  click on ok
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue. Googled arround found nothing, and gues what:
It was the a checkbox in the main Android SDK and AVD Manager.

1. Click: available packages
2. Then select: Android Repository
   Then you see the "some packages were found but are not compatible updates" message, which is why you created this question.
   On the bottom of the form, you can see: 4 buttons and 1 checkbox.

Make sure you Uncheck: "Display updates only" when it is unchecked, you see the whole SDK list with Android 3.2 etc.

Comment: I have the same problem... I am using Linux Mint and they are still not showing up. :( If anyone else can offer some advice I'd be grateful.

Answer (score 1):

Steps for installing Development Environment.

1. Download Android SDK and Install it.
2. Install Android API’s for different android versions. The latest version is Android 2.3.
3. Download and Install Eclipse Install ADT plugin.
4. Create AVD (Android Virtual Device) for testing the applications.

I think you did not linked your Android SDK folder with Eclipse ADT plugin. Goto Window->Preference->Android browse your Android SDK if you have installed ADT plugin.

There are many resources available online. Here is a blog post where you find some good links to resources which help you in installing Android Development Environment.

[Getting Started with Android](http://droidfanatic.blogspot.com/2010/12/getting-started-with-android.html)

If you still didn't able to do it. Let me know your specific problem, where you got struck.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is already an answer that probably works for most people (unchecking the box), but since that did not work for this install I have on Linux Mint, this did work:
(not my website)
http://blog.netscribe.us/blog/post/Step-by-Step-Guide-on-How-to-Install-Android-SDK-Offline-%28not-completely-offline%29.aspx

Basically, download the zip for the package you want and extract it to /platforms/.