# I cannot create a new android project using eclipse

Tags: android

I cannot create a new Android project using eclipse as the options available for creating new project are: Android Application Project, Android Project Using Existing Codes, Android sample Project, Android Test Project.
No option for Android Project is available.

Comment: just use Android Application Project

Comment: ROFL...so as per this user, there is a difference between Android Project and Android application project !!

Comment: @PareshMayani making fun of beginners, eh? not cool.

Comment: Create android application project its a new android project only

Comment: @VinayWadhwa Sorry dear, i wasn't making fun but Question must be real like. Before asking question they should atleast do some R&D. Here in this case, they have atleast try to create project by using "Android application project".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android Application Project itself is Android project.
Use Android Application Project

Answer (score 1):

Use Android Application Project

Answer (score 1):

-have you installed the android plugin (ADT) for elcipse?
if you did, right click in the navigator - > other - > Android - > Android project

Comment: If the OP hadn't installed the ADT then there wouldn't have been any Android project options available.

Comment: i know, but others who end up on this post looking for a similar answer could use this :-)

Comment: @Squonk OP has already mentioned that they have options: Android application project, Android project using existing codes.

Comment: @PareshMayani - My point is why did Vinay Wadhwa ask **have you installed the android plugin (ADT)...?"** It was obvious that the OP already had.

Comment: @VinayWadhwa : Yes but the OP has stated in the question **"No option for Android Project is available."** but you suggest using "navigator - > other - > Android - > **Android project**".

Comment: @VinayWadhwa : But pinkdawn (in a comment on the OP's question) and flamingo in another answer have already recommended the OP chooses "Android Application Project" but your answer says to use "Android project" which the OP has explained isn't an option. If you're trying to help then please be accurate with your advice.

Answer (score 0):

Use eclipse Indigo version and install AVD and SDK as suggested the steps in android developers site
here is the same 
[Android SDK and AVD Manager installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4692852/android-sdk-and-avd-manager-installation)