# Eclipse: Cannot create "Android Project"

Tags: java, android, sdk

I've installed everything correctly, and made an AVD,
But when I click "new project", everything *but* android project comes up...

Everything so far has worked; Is "android Application Project" now used instead of "Android Project"?

Apparently I don't have enough rep to post an image :(. so here
s a link for proof: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sb4gl.png

**Is this guy's answer true?:** [I cannot create a new android project using eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11428836/i-cannot-create-a-new-android-project-using-eclipse)

Comment: "Is this answer true?" What keeps you from trying it and seeing if it works? Your computer won't blow up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Android Application Project as far as i am aware is the new/current name used instead of Android Project. If you are following a tutorial at all or any books, be aware that the layout, names, etc may have changed.... they may even be located elsewhere or sometimes included already. I say this as i have recently been following some tutorials for Android development.

Good luck... (hope this helps)